# How to parse a csv file which has special characters?

Tags: java, csv

> I have a csv file stored in server location i try to parse it through my engine 
>   like this         `br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"));`

here path is csv present inside server location for ex: /home/test/test.csv

When i try get the the data from csv from logs it prints in wrong format Cï¿½drick instead of Cédrick .Could anyone let me know what might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change "UTF-8" by "ISO-8859-1".

Also try to open your file in another program like excel because I think it was saved with the wrong encoding.

Regards